# How to prefill Mobile Number, Type of business in stripe express onboarding?

Tags: java, express, stripe-payments

Can I prefill the Mobile Number? as I have prefilled the Email

[image: Unable to refill Mobile Number]

Can I prefill the Type of business? as I have prefilled the Country

[image: Unable to prefill Type of business]

Unable to prefill phone number, Type of business in stripe onboarding express account. But other fields are prefilling except these fields.
I have referred:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update?lang=java to update accounts API

```
    Map<String, Object> addressParams = new HashMap<>();
    addressParams.put("country", "AU");
    if (accountInfo.get("companyAddressLine1") != null)
    addressParams.put("line1", accountInfo.get("companyAddressLine1"));
    if (accountInfo.get("companyAddressLine2") != null)
    addressParams.put("line2", accountInfo.get("companyAddressLine2"));
    if (accountInfo.get("companyAddressCity") != null)
    addressParams.put("city", accountInfo.get("companyAddressCity"));
    if (accountInfo.get("companyAddressState") != null)
    addressParams.put("state", accountInfo.get("companyAddressState"));
    if (accountInfo.get("companyAddressPostalCode") != null)
    addressParams.put("postal_code", accountInfo.get("companyAddressPostalCode"));

    Map<String, Object> companyParams = new HashMap<>();
    companyParams.put("address", addressParams);
    if (accountInfo.get("companyPhone") != null)
    companyParams.put("phone", accountInfo.get("companyPhone"));
    if (accountInfo.get("abnNumber") != null)
    companyParams.put("tax_id", accountInfo.get("abnNumber"));
    if (accountInfo.get("companyName") != null)
    companyParams.put("name", accountInfo.get("companyName"));

    Map<String, Object> businessProfileParams = new HashMap<>();
     businessProfileParams.put("support_address", addressParams);
    businessProfileParams.put("product_description","test");

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("business_type", "company");
    if (accountInfo.get("companyEmail") != null)
    params.put("email", accountInfo.get("companyEmail"));
    params.put("business_profile", businessProfileParams);
    params.put("company", companyParams);

    Account updatedAccount = account.update(params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone and email input in the screenshot is used for Express authentication and is associated with the User on the account. The platform cannot pre-fill this User data. The phone & email which the you have pre-filled using the Accounts API is associated with the company/business on this account.

Yes, you should be able to prefill the type of business. I'd suggest [retrieving the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve) to verify if the `business_type` has been set before creating the onboarding link.

Comment: I am able to prefill the email. I am unable to prefill the phone number. I am using accounts api

Comment: For business_type, when I set business_type as 'individual' it's prefilling, but when I set business_type as 'company' it's blank.

Comment: I have set the business_type before creating the onboarding link

Comment: The `business_type` showing as blank when you set it as `company` sounds like a bug, you'll probably want to reach out to Stripe Support to clarify if this is expected behaviour

Comment: I can prefill the phone number, right?

Comment: you shouldn't be able to pre-fill the phone number in that screenshot afaik